# In react js, how can I create a read-only ref to a DOM element?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-ref

I'm currently working on a react component library, and I'd like to create a ref to child from parent and access properties like margin, color, and so on! But I don't want to change it; how can I accomplish this in react js?

Comment: Define an `useRef` value for your child, then use 
`childRef.current.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(childRef.current)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.getComputedStyle(childRef.current)
```